# Using tab-completed directory names in bash

Tags: android, bash

I'm trying to make a simple bash script to use adb to push a folder of music to my phone. This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR_PATH="'${1::-1}'/"
VAR_PATH="${VAR_PATH/"-"/"\-"}"
MUSIC_PATH=/storage/emulated/0/Music/
if [[ -d $1 ]]; then
        echo adb push $VAR_PATH $MUSIC_PATH
        adb push $VAR_PATH $MUSIC_PATH
fi
```

when I run this command,

```
./push-to-phone.sh 'The xx - I See You 2017 y'/
```

This is what echoes:

```
adb push 'The xx \- I See You 2017 y'/ /storage/emulated/0/Music/
```

followed by a bunch of errors as adb tries to parse each space individually. However, when the exact same command (minus the escape on the hyphen) is run through a bash autocomplete, it works perfectly. Can someone explain what's going on and how I can fix it?

I've already tried using printf to escape all the spaces, but the same problem occurs.

Comment: Can you tell me what `${1::-1} ` is meant to expand to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote your variables when invoking `adb` and skip adding extra single quotes.  They're only added after the variable is already expanded, so you're the first argument to `adb push` is `'The` and the next is `xx` but it's still all getting word split.

Instead just do

```
adb push "$VAR_PATH" "$MUSIC_PATH"
```

and don't put the single quotes around `VAR_PATH` when creating it:

```
VAR_PATH="$1"
```

should do based on your example

Also, it's not generally good style to use upper case for your variables lest they collide with environment variables, so consider switching yours to lower case.